# How to absorb swipe motion only in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

I am looking for a widget, analogous to [AbsorbPointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html), that would absorb swipe motions. The goal is to allow "tap" actions to go through to the child but let the parent handle the "swipe" motions.

If possible I would like to also differentiate absorption depending on direction (only absorb vertical motion for example).

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

you can use [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to detect tap behavior and swipe motions

```dart
GestureDetector(
  child: Widget(), // your widget
  onTap: () { // Tap behavior listener
    // your tap logic
  }, 
  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) { // Swipe behavior listener
    print(details.primaryDelta); // Positive is left to right, Negative is right to left
    // your swipe logic 
  },  
)
```

using two `GestureDetector` you can warp the parent with listener `onHorizontalDragUpdate` to detect the swipe motion while warping the child with listener `onTap` to detect the tap behavior